# How to compare the order of elements in cyclic groups?

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-theory

In a cyclic group with randomly looking behavior like the one used in secp256k1, is there any known efficient algorithm to compare the order of two randomly given elements $P_1$ and $P_2$ and find out which one will appear first starting from a known generator point of the cycle? If such algorithm exists, would that be considered a weakness?!

Consider that we have two known integers $a$ and $b$ so that $a>b$. Taking $P_1=a\times G$ and $P_2=b\times G$ we can say $P_2$ has a greater order in the cycle, meaning that starting from the generator point it will appear before than $P_1$.

By this definition is there any known algorithm based which one can compare the order of two random elements of the group $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: You really shouldn't use the word "order" here. "Order" in group theory has a precise meaning, and using it to mean anything else creates confusion.

Comment: What word do you suggest to use instead of "order"?

Comment: The integer $a$ such that $P_1 = a\cdot G$ is called the *discrete logarithm of $P_1$* (relative to $G$), and similarly for $P_2$, so you could say that you wish to show that the discrete logarithm of $P_2$ is larger than that of $P_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By this definition is there any known algorithm based which one can
>   compare the order of two random elements of the group $P_1$ and $P_2$?

**No, such an algorithm would allow for an easy break of the elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem.** But as this problem is assumed hard for secure curves like `secp256k1` us knowing such an algorithm is impossible.

To see this fix the reference generator $G$ to the standard one for the curve with the generator having order $q$. Furthermore let $P=xG$ be the challenge point for which we want to recover $x$. Now define $a=1$ and $b=q-1$.

1. Compute $m=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $M=mG$.
2. Check whether $M=P$ and if so, return $m$.
3. Check whether $M<P$ using the conjectured algorithm. If this is true, set $a\gets m$, otherwise set $b\gets m$.
4. Go to 1.

This is a standard binary search as you may have recognized and it will find the discrete logarithm in about $\log_2 q$ scalar point multiplications and algorithm evaluations which is quite efficient.

Comment: And, best known algorithms for ECDLP are [baby-step giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) and [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) and these  requires $\mathcal{O}\sqrt{n}$ comlexity.